# Stored procedure INSERT INTO with different column count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures, insert

I have a stored procedure and I am trying to insert some data into a temporary table. However, the stored procedure only contains 3 of these columns (col1 through col3), and I am trying to update one and have the last one auto-incremented.

```
DECLARE @customCol VARCHAR(12)  

CREATE TABLE #table 
(
    col1 VARCHAR(50), 
    col2 INT, 
    col3 INT,
    customCol VARCHAR(12), 
    rowNumber INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
)

INSERT INTO #table (col1, col2, col3, customCol, rowNumber) 
    EXEC sp @var1, @var2

UPDATE #table 
SET customCol = @customCol 
WHERE rowNumber = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #table)
```

My issue is that whenever I try this, I get the error shown below

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I understand that this is because the stored procedure only contains 3 columns and is missing 2 other values, any tips on how I can adjust my query to fix this problem?

Comment: Just specify three columns in the insert statement. because rowNumber  is auto generated and customCol is filled by update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify three columns in the insert statement and use `IDENTITY(1,1)` instead of `IDENTITY`

```
--Create tables
CREATE TABLE #table (
col1 VARCHAR(50), 
col2 INT, 
col3 INT,
customCol VARCHAR(12), 
rowNumber INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
)

--Insert into first temp table
INSERT INTO #table (col1, col2, col3) EXEC Sp  @var1,@var2


UPDATE #table SET customCol = @customCol WHERE rowNumber = (SELECT MAX(rowNumber) FROM #table2)
```